# PHPExcel + mPDF class 'Mpdf' not found

Tags: phpexcel, mpdf

After created tcPDF File is 800+kB but totally empty/White i looked into Composer and mPDF. Installed on local machine and copied Folder 'vendor' to my Webspace.

My file-structure :

```
/WWW/class/my-own-classes
          /PHPExcel
          /vendor/composer
          /vendor/mpdf/mpdf
    /project1/../../../executing-file.php
    /project2/
```

I combined my previous autoloader plus composer-autoloaderlike following.

```
require_once '../../DomainNameClass.php';
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path = New DomainName("project","intern");
    if($class == 'PHPExcel') {
        require_once $path->classPath . $class . '.php';
    } 
    elseif ( file_exists( $path->classPath . strtolower($class) . 'Class.php' ) ) {
        require_once $path->classPath . strtolower($class) . 'Class.php';
    }
});

$path = New DomainName("dinelco","intern");
require $path -> classPath . "/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Out of my PHPExcel-Helper class :

```
private function setMPDF() {
        $this->rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
        $this->rendererLibrary = 'mpdf7.0.0';
        $this->rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src';
    }
```

mPDF.php from PHPExcel will throw an exception if this file isn't found.
Since now I don't get an exception I assume my path is correct.

But: Test echo from PHPExcel/mPDF.php Looks good to me :

```
"found: /is/htdocs/something/www/class/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php"
```

And then:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mpdf' not found in /is/htdocs/something/www/class/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/mPDF.php on line 96
```

On Github mPDF I read about Version but I got the last stable one (7.0) which shall be called like "new mPDF();" instead "new \Mpdf\Mpdf();" but that didn't work out either.

Looking for some hrs now.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: what is your mpdf version ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to use

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

instead of

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
```

In my case it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this way.

```
    try {
        $mpdf = new Mpdf();
    } catch (MpdfException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used composer to install MPDF, you need indicate in your PHP code:

```
 use \Mpdf\Mpdf;
```

And, later, you can use:

```
$myMpdfVar = new Mpdf();
```